# How to reference an image from JS file in packaged Shiny app?

Tags: javascript, r, shiny

I am creating an R package which provides some helper functions to build a Shiny app.

One of the JS files packaged with the app needs to reference an image file. But I can't figure out how to reference it.

Currently, the js file is located in

> my_package/inst/www/js/my_jsfile.js

This file needs to reference

> my_package/inst/www/img/my_img.gif

In the JS file, what should the relative URL to the image be?

I tried various options, such as the following, which do not work, when launching in a Shiny app built with the package:

> ../my_img.gif
>
> www/img/my_img.gif

My JS looks like this:

```
function showRecordingIcon() {

  var img = document.createElement("img");
  img.style.display = "block";
  img.src =  "img/record.gif";
  img.width = "280";
  img.height = "280";
}
```

This was working before I packaged it.

Answer (score 2):

If your goal is to get file path from the inst folder in your package on the user system, try:

```
system.file('www/js/my_file.js', package = 'NAMEOFYOURPACKAGE', mustWork = T)
```

Comment: I am talking about what the URL/path should be in the JS file, not the R code.

Comment: Oh, seems like this should work then `img/my_img.gif`

Comment: Alas, it does not! Just to be clear, the JS file is located in a package my_app/inst/www/js/my_jsfile.js. I then install this package and in another directory try to use the package function to create the Shiny HTML.

Comment: To confirm, the JS file in the package loads, but the image sourced in the JS file does not.

Comment: What does your browser console error read?

Comment: Can you show the javascript call you are making?

Comment: Added to main post.

Answer (score 1):

Did you use `shiny::addResourcePath("img", "/path/to/img/folder")`

Something like `shiny::addResourcePath("img", system.file('www', 'img', package = 'NAMEOFYOURPACKAGE', mustWork = T)`

Next, you can refer to it as "img/record.gif"

Answer (score 0):

The [**../**](https://www.w3schools.com/html/html_filepaths.asp) means that it goes to the parent directory.

```
../img/my_img.gif
```

Comment: Nope, unfortunately not.

Just to confirm, everything works with an absolute URL.